# Assembly load failure

Tags: c#, c++, process, .net-assembly, mixed-mode

I am having a managed assembly load issue stemming from a spawned mixed-mode process. See below for details. Assume BinPath and ExecutablePath are two valid paths that are not the same.

I have a web app that was started in BinPath, and creates a process using the following ProcessStartInfo:

```
new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = ExecutablePath + "PerformanceRunner.exe",
    WorkingDirectory = ExecutablePath ,
    UseShellExecute = true                
};
```

PerformanceRunner.exe then successfully loads several unmanaged DLLs which reside in ExecutablePath (this is verified by looking at the Modules window in VS). It then attempts to load a managed assembly also located in ExecutablePath, but this fails. Here is the fusion log of this - note that BinPath is "G:\TOPSS\TOPSS New\Common\Service\Bin" and the managed assembly is TPSSCDQ.dll. TPSSCDQ resides in ExecutablePath.

---

> *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (11/29/2012 @ 4:16:11 PM) ***
>
> The operation failed. Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
>   executable  G:\TOPSS\TOPSS New\Common\Service\Bin\PerformanceRunner.exe
>
> ---
>
> **=== Pre-bind state information ===**
>
> **LOG**: User = CORP\lbhra
>
> **LOG**: DisplayName = TpssCDQ, Version=1.0.4612.26218, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null  (Fully-specified)
>
> **LOG**: Appbase = file:///G:/TOPSS/TOPSS New/Common/Service/Bin/
>
> **LOG**: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>
> **LOG**: Dynamic Base = NULL
>
> **LOG**: Cache Base = NULL
>
> **LOG**: AppName = PerformanceRunner.exe
>
> **Calling assembly : (Unknown).**
>
> **===**
>
> **LOG**: This bind starts in default load context.
>
> **LOG**: No application configuration file found.
>
> **LOG**: Using host configuration file:
>
> **LOG**: Using machine configuration file from 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>
> **LOG**: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
>
> **LOG**: Attempting download of new URL file:///G:/TOPSS/TOPSS New/Common/Service/Bin/TpssCDQ.DLL.
>
> **LOG**: Attempting download of new URL file:///G:/TOPSS/TOPSS New/Common/Service/Bin/TpssCDQ/TpssCDQ.DLL.
>
> **LOG**: Attempting download of new URL file:///G:/TOPSS/TOPSS
>   New/Common/Service/Bin/TpssCDQ.EXE.
>
> **LOG**: Attempting download of new URL file:///G:/TOPSS/TOPSS New/Common/Service/Bin/TpssCDQ/TpssCDQ.EXE.
>
> **LOG**: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
>
> ---

I don't fully understand what the PrivatePath, Appbase or Dynamicbase is, but shouldn't at least one of these paths be the working directory (ExecutablePath)? I have verified using GetCurrentDirectory that the working directory is set correctly. I'd really appreciate a hand with this, as I am rather confused.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it should be looking in the root folder where the executable is stored. It won't look in the working directory - but I understand in this instance, those paths are the same. If you look at your error message, `APPBASE` is set correctly, so I think it's looking in the right place, but not finding it for other reasons.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.90).aspx

Other things to check:

- Do you have any assembly load hints in your app/machine config files?
- Is the managed DLL built for the correct platform?
- Has the managed DLL been renamed at all - does the filename match the manifest?
- Are all the managed DLL's dependencies stored in the same location?

Also, how are you loading this assembly? Is it listed as a reference of the project, or are you calling Assembly.Load (or similar)?